# Flutter - FlatButton Fill available horizontal space

Tags: flutter, button, width

I'm trying to have a UI in such a way that the number of buttons in a row changes depending on available information. More specifically, there will always be one `FlatButton` that links to an external page, but if a download link is also provided, then there will be a second `FlatButton` in the row.

On the website that currently exists, we have this working for [one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7PUR.png) versus [two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJjbL.png), but I can't get the one button to horizontally expand to fill the available space.

At the moment, I add the `FlatButton`s to a `List<Widget>` variable that I pass as the children for a row. I have tried using `Flex -> Expanded`, `SizedBox.expand`, `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` and every solution I have found on this site so far to get it to expand, but every solution I have tried have all resulted in `forced infinite width` or `unbounded width` or `non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded`.

Here's my code in the `build` method as it currently stands:

```
List<Widget> fullTextDownloadBtns = new List();
if (this.fullArticleUrl != null && this.fullArticleUrl.isNotEmpty) {
  fullTextDownloadBtns.add(
    FlatButton(
      color: Color(0x66629c44),
      onPressed: _openFullArticle,
      child: Text(
        "Full Article",
        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff629c44)),
      ),
    )
  );
}

if (this.downloadUrl != null && this.downloadUrl.isNotEmpty) {
  fullTextDownloadBtns.add(
    FlatButton(
      color: Color(0x664d69b1),
      onPressed: _download,
      child: Text(
        "Download",
        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff4d69b1)),
      ),
    )
  );
}

return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff0096b0)
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          // ...related image, title

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: fullTextDownloadBtns,
            ),
          ), // Read full article & download PDF

          // ... Authors, excerpt/description, like/share buttons, comments
        ],
      )
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping your buttons with Expanded is the way to go here (I tried it with your code) :

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){},
        child: Text("1")),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){},
        child: Text("2")),
    )
  ],
),
```

By the way, since the SDK 2.2.2 (in your pubspec.yaml), you can use conditions within the children list :

```
children: [
  if(true == true)
  FlatButton(
    onPressed: (){},
    child: Text("1")),
],
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly. I tried adding `Expanded` elements to the `List` but for some reason that caused `unbounded width` errors. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that you can adjust the width of the buttons border by using the 'width' property inside 'side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, **width: 2.2**)'.

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
             side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 2.2),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: (Text('BUTTON NAME')),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Couldn't find how to change the border outline width for a long while on here. So thought I might add it here. Maybe help some other noobie like me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Row widget and use two Expanded widget which their child are FlatButton.implement the condition fot them seperately sth like:

```
Row(
children:[
trueCondition ? Expanded(
child: FlatButton()
) : SizedBox()
]
)
```